# How to create index in SQL from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing

The scenario is as follows. I need to drop a particular index at the beginning of the  C# application. After all the insert sql statements which are part of processing are complete, I need to create the index again.

The reason I need index drop and creation as part of the application is because I will be giving this application to the deployment team. The deployment team will then be running the application in production.

Is inline sql the best way to create an index - clustered or non-clustered in SQL server from C#?

Or is it there any other way?

Comment: You write a SQL script - in any text editor of your choice - and you execute it ...... what is the question, really?!?!?

Comment: I wouyld like to trigger it via C#.  I know how to trigger regular dynamic sql and stored procedure from C#. Was just wondering how to trigger creation of an index from C#. I am running this as part of a c# application which I will hand over to deployment team to run in production

Comment: It might help if you stop using the word "trigger", or at least explain what it means for you. If your basic question is how to create an index from C#, then you can just write a script as @marc_s said, or [use SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.index.aspx).

Comment: Trigger = "kick off" in this scenario. I know there is the sql trigger but i think it is pretty clear in this particular context what I mean by trigger.

Comment: If you are creating indexes from a C# application, something may have gone wrong.

Comment: I have reworded the title and the question. Hope that what I am asking is more clear now.

Comment: The situation is a little complicated to explain but I need to drop a particular index at the beginning of the application. After all the  insert sql statements which are part of processing are complete, I need to create the index again. The reason I need index drop and creation as part of the application is because I will be giving this application to the deployment team. The deployment team will then be running the application in production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) and simply send along a `CREATE INDEX` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is phrased a little strangely.

Are you asking how to create indexes or how to cause the statistics to be updated (for the optimizers to decide which index would give the answer to a query the quickest) ?

Creating indexes is with CREATE INDEX.

Causing the stats to be recalculated is UPDATE STATISTICS.

Both can be done via C# or any other method.

An index is updated whenever anything is created/updated/deleted.

Comment: I know how to trigger regular dynamic sql and stored procedure from C#. Was just wondering how to trigger creation of an index from C#.I am running this as part of a c# application which I will hand over to deployment team to run in production

Comment: Please see the comments under my question for some more clarifications.